# Google Line Chart Two series

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a google line chart that is loaded with some json data. I now need to figure out how to dynamically add another point to this chart but separate from the lines drawn on load.

This is my code so far:

```
function drawchart() {
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Arm');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Weight');

  for (var i = 0; i < chartdatax.length; i++) {
      chartData.addRow([parseFloat(chartdatax[i]), parseFloat(chartdatay[i])]);
      };

   var options2 = {
       height: 500,
       hAxis: {
          title: 'Arm C.G',
          gridlines: {
            count: 20
        }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Weight',
          gridlines: {
            count: 20
        }
        },
      chartArea: {top:40, width: "70%", height: "75%"},

      legend: { position: 'none' },
      pointSize: 5
    };

   myLineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('myChart2'));

    myLineChart.draw(chartData, options2);
}
```

My chart looks like this:

[image]

This loads at runtime. Now I have two inputboxes with values and when a user clicks a button I want to push that point onto the chart in a different color so it looks something like this:

[image]

I've tried this but it breaks the chart:

```
var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Arm');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'userenteredpoint1');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'userenteredpoint1');

  for (var i = 0; i < chartdatax.length; i++) {
      chartData.addRow([parseFloat(chartdatax[i]), parseFloat(chartdatay[i]), parseFloat(chartdatap[i]), parseFloat(chartdataz[i])]);
      };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/bb5enLm9/14/

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle example with your code?

Comment: @WhiteHat All user-entered points should be connected, but separate from the other points on the chart that are loaded on runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to handle it. Each additional point added will continue in the same series.

When adding multiple series, the first column is always used as the X value.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': drawchart});

var chartData;
var myLineChart;
var options;

function drawchart() {
  document.getElementById('addPoint').addEventListener('click', addUserPoint, false);

  chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Arm');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Weight');

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    chartData.addRow([
      parseFloat(i),
      parseFloat(i * 1.5)
    ]);
  };

  options = {
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Arm C.G',
      gridlines: {
        count: 20
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Weight',
      gridlines: {
        count: 20
      }
    },
    chartArea: {top:40, width: "70%", height: "75%"},
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    pointSize: 5
  };

  myLineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
  myLineChart.draw(chartData, options);
}

function addUserPoint() {
  if (chartData.getNumberOfColumns() === 2) {
    chartData.addColumn('number', 'User Input Y');
  }
  chartData.addRow([
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('userX').value),
    null,
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('userY').value)
  ]);
  myLineChart.draw(chartData, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
<input type="text" id="userX" />
<input type="text" id="userY" />
<input type="button" id="addPoint" value="Add Point" />
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I wanted. I hadn't thought of using a separate function like you did. That is an elegant solution sir! I appreciate it very much :)

Comment: cheers, glad to help. I will look at other question again when I have more time...

Comment: Thank you, this is what makes Stackoverflow such a great community. I hope I learn enough to one day contribute back.